# Access query to email

Tags: database, windows, vba, ms-access, email

I've got the attached query, which shows several rows (there is more data) but only 2 email address. I would like to send the corresponding rows to their relevant email address. All these details change every week, and there will be more (and sometimes less) email addresses, so I need to keep the data coming from this form (rather than static addresses). I've tried making a report, and can manage to send that to the email address, but I get multiple forms/emails for this report. The query will show a lot of records, so this is not an acceptable solution.

Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT - I've attached the tables which show the data. I just want to send each company their own few rows by any means possible. Please help :)

[image: Table Layout]

Thanks.

[image: Querydetails]

My Full code:

```
Dim rS As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbS As DAO.Database
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Folderpath As String
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem

Set dbS = CurrentDb()
Set rS = dbS.OpenRecordset("Select DISTINCT email, [CompName], [MainContact] FROM q66NonConfirmedTimesheets")
Do While Not rS.EOF

myemail = rS!email
mycompname = rS!CompName
myMainContact = rS!MainContact

'My Email the report
Folderpath = "C:\Reports\"
Folderpath = Folderpath & "WeeklyTimesheet, " & [mycompname] & " - " & Format(date, "dd mmm yyyy") & ".pdf"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt01UnconfirmedTimesheets", acViewPreview, , "email = '" & myemail & "'"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", Folderpath, False
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Rpt01UnconfirmedTimesheets"

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If
Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oEmailItem
.to = [myemail]
.Subject = "Unconfirmed Timesheets"
.Body = "Automatic email from my database"
.Attachments.Add Folderpath
.Display
End With
'End of my emailing report

rS.MoveNext
Loop
Set oEmailItem = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
Set rS = Nothing
Set dbS = Nothing

End Sub
```

and I've added into my "Onload" event on the Report:

```
Me.Filter = "[email]='" & myemail & "'"
```

Comment: You're going to have to either use VBA, a report, or a form to filter each set of `WorkhourID` by an email, if that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think I have explained it very clearly. There is more data than what is shown here. Each rows has got dates, times etc. Please tell me how I can send (in this case) the first 7 rows to the email address them@gmail.com and the the other 5 (in this case) to me@gmail.com

Comment: So your question is actually about how to send the data as an email, or do you have that working?

Comment: I can send reports via email, (either each line as an email or the whole report as on email (pdf). Just need a way to split into 2 (or more if the query shows more) as per the email address

Comment: Okay. What's the set up for this? A button on a form, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a recordset in VBA that contains the unique email addresses.
Loop through the recordset, opening your report, filtering on the email address and emailing the report. Air code:

```
Dim rS as DAO.Recordset
Dim dbS as DAO.Database
Set dbS = CurrentDb()
Set rS = dbS.OpenRecordset("Select DISTINCT emailaddress FROM <yourquery>",DbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rS.EOF
<sometempvar> = rS!emailaddress
'your code to email filtered report using <sometempvar>'
rS.MoveNext
Loop
Set rS = Nothing
Set dbS = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but I need some more help. It's failing at the openRecordSet line. I've tried everything I can think of. Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I get the one report sending to both email address. Just need to filter before it creates the report

Comment: You say the code is failing on OpenRecordSet, How can anyone help if you don't tell us what the error is?

Comment: Sorry, thought my last comment explained that I clear the error (I forgot to take out the < and >. I'm getting the same report to both emails. Any idea on how I can filter the report based on which email it's sending to?

Comment: You need to filter the report. There are many ways to do this. One would be to use a tempvar. In the open event of the report add the line Me.Filter = "email='" & <sometempvar> & "'". Set the tempvar as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: Ok, done that, it's now producing the emails and reports, but the reports are blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my code above to reflect all the changes so far.

Comment: OK, sorted. I've updated my code and it all works. After searching through google I found another way to filter and that was to open the query up, with filter, save it then close it. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query to only return the emails **and** specify the query to return unique values only, there is an option for that in the query editor:

[image]